# Kafka Transactions are not rolling back after interrupting current thread on timeout

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to interrupt current thread if http request times out. I have setup PlatformTransactionManager for Kafka Transactions as a bean. I'm using @Transactional annotation at method level. We are publishing message in 3 topics. After publishing message in first topic I'm putting Thread.sleep(5000) and current thread is interrupting from filter if execution takes more than 6 seconds. So here call is getting interrupted but message is getting published to Kafka. We are just producing the message. We are not consuming any message but able to see message in our internal Kafka Inspection Tool. We are using KafkaTemplate.send() to send message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Producer records are always written to the log, even if rolled back. There is a special record in the slot following the published record(s) to indicate whether the transaction was committed or rolled back.

Consumers' `isolation.level` is `read_uncommitted` by default; you need to set it to `read_committed` to avoid seeing rolled-back records.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_isolation.level